# Qt Creator: AlwaysStaysOnTop blocks open file prompt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a push button on my main window that allows the user to select a file to open.

```
std::fstream infile;
std::string filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("TXT file"), qApp->applicationDirPath (),tr("TXT File (*.txt)")).toStdString();
if (filename.empty())
    return;

infile.open(filename, std::fstream:: in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
if (true) {
//Does stuff with the data
}
infile.close();
```

This normally works fine, and I've used it in previous gui qt applications.  However, for this application the mainwindow (upon its setup) sets its windowsflags as follows:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint| Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

This creates a problem as the main window attempts to always stay on top (and thus prevents the open file window from appearing).  Without the staysontop flag the file dialog works correctly.

Is there a way to temporarily disable this flag (so I can disable when the push button is clicked and then reenable when the file dialog is complete)?

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint| ~Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

This seems to be the most common suggested solution, but doesn't work for me.  I believe this is because the window has to be recreated for the changes to the window flag to be registered -- however, I believe that if I killed the main window the file dialog would go out of scope too?

In summary, I am trying to find a work around to have the main window always on top except for when I am trying to select a file to open (the file dialog being triggered by a push button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the flags but rather a timer emitting signals which updated the window position:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_pos()));
timer->start(50);
```

Where the update_pos function is as follows:

```
void MainWindow::update_pos(){
 RECT rect;
 if (GetWindowRect(target_window, &rect)) {
   SetWindowPos((HWND)this->winId(), HWND_TOPMOST, rect.left, rect.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
 } else {
   //maybe window was closed
   qDebug() << "GetWindowRect failed";
   QApplication::quit();
 }
```

}

Whenever the update_pos function was called it would push the main window to the top (and thus above the open file dialog).